# Questions concerning elements in $F = \big\{f: \{1, 2, 3\} \to \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}\big\}$.

Tags: combinatorics, functions, discrete-mathematics

a) Find and simplify the number of functions $f \in F$ so that $f(1) = 4$.

My attempt: there is $1$ choice for $f(1)$, and $5$ choices for $f(2)$ and $5$ choices for $f(3)$, thus $1\cdot 5\cdot 5 = 25$ functions

b) Find and simplify the number of one-to-one functions $f \in F$ so that $f(1) \geq 4$

Attempt: since there are $2$ choices for $f(1)$, I broke it into $2$ cases, one when $f(1) = 5$ and when $f(1) = 4$.

Then there are $(1 \cdot 4 \cdot 3) + (1 \cdot 4 \cdot 3) = 24$ choices.

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, it is. You could also have done the second problem in one step: there are $2$ choices for $f(1)$, and no matter how you make that choice, there are $4$ for $f(2)$ and then $3$ for $f(3)$, for a total of $2\cdot4\cdot3=24$.

Comment: Thank you so much! That seems a lot simpler!

Comment: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, both solutions are correct. Your reasoning for (a) is spot-on.

For (b), you could have simplified your reasoning a little -- there are $2$ choices for $f(1)$, and then $4$ choices for $f(2)$, and $3$ choices for $f(3)$. By the [rule of product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product), you have $2 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 = 24$ choices in total.